# Tablas en BOOTSTRAP 3

Tags: bootstrap, bootstrap-3

[image: Tengo un problema para que mi maquetado luzca asi:]

[image: De forma que luce asi]

**Necesito que La columna anidada de la fila dos abarque toda la columna** 
Mi codigo es este:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row"> <!-- FILA 1-->
        <div class="col-md-12">
                <h1>Prueba</h1>
                <p>
                Leonardo da Vinci (Leonardo di ser Piero da Vinci Loudspeaker.svg escuchar) (Vinci, 15 de abril de 14522 -Amboise, 2 de mayo de 1519) fue un polímata florentino del Renacimiento italiano. Fue a la vez pintor, anatomista, arquitecto, paleontólogo,3 artista, botánico, científico, escritor, escultor, filósofo, ingeniero, inventor, músico, poeta y urbanista. Murió acompañado de su fiel Francesco Melzi, a quien legó sus proyectos, diseños y pinturas.2 Tras pasar su infancia en su 
                </p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row"> <!-- FILA 2-->
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <h1>Prueba</h1>
                <p>
                Leonardo da Vinci (Leonardo di ser Piero da Vinci Loudspeaker.svg escuchar) (Vinci, 15 de abril de 14522 -Amboise, 2 de mayo de 1519) fue un polímata florentino del Renacimiento italiano. Fue a la vez pintor, anatomista, arquitecto, paleontólogo,3 artista, botánico, científico, escritor, escultor, filósofo, ingeniero, inventor, músico, poeta y urbanista. Murió acompañado de su fiel Francesco Melzi, a quien legó sus proyectos, diseños y pinturas.2 Tras pasar su infancia en su 
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <h1>Prueba</h1>
                <p>
                Leonardo da Vinci (Leonardo di ser Piero da Vinci Loudspeaker.svg escuchar) (Vinci, 15 de abril de 14522 -Amboise, 2 de mayo de 1519) fue un polímata florentino del Renacimiento italiano. Fue a la vez pintor, anatomista, arquitecto, paleontólogo,3 artista, botánico, científico, escritor, escultor, filósofo, ingeniero, inventor, músico, poeta y urbanista. Murió acompañado de su fiel Francesco Melzi, a quien legó sus proyectos, diseños y pinturas.2 Tras pasar su infancia en su 
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <h1>Prueba</h1>
            <p>
            Leonardo da Vinci (Leonardo di ser Piero da Vinci Loudspeaker.svg escuchar) (Vinci, 15 de abril de 14522 -Amboise, 2 de mayo de 1519) fue un polímata florentino del Renacimiento italiano. Fue a la vez pintor, anatomista, arquitecto, paleontólogo,3 artista, botánico, científico, escritor, escultor, filósofo, ingeniero, inventor, músico, poeta y urbanista. Murió acompañado de su fiel Francesco Melzi, a quien legó sus proyectos, diseños y pinturas.2 Tras pasar su infancia en su 
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>





    <div class="row"> <!--Fila 3-->
        <div class="col-md-3">
                <h1>Prueba</h1>
                <p>
                Leonardo da Vinci (Leonardo di ser Piero da Vinci Loudspeaker.svg escuchar) (Vinci, 15 de abril de 14522 -Amboise, 2 de mayo de 1519) fue un polímata florentino del Renacimiento italiano. Fue a la vez pintor, anatomista, arquitecto, paleontólogo,3 artista, botánico, científico, escritor, escultor, filósofo, ingeniero, inventor, músico, poeta y urbanista. Murió acompañado de su fiel Francesco Melzi, a quien legó sus proyectos, diseños y pinturas.2 Tras pasar su infancia en su 
                </p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
                <h1>Prueba</h1>
                <p>
                Leonardo da Vinci (Leonardo di ser Piero da Vinci Loudspeaker.svg escuchar) (Vinci, 15 de abril de 14522 -Amboise, 2 de mayo de 1519) fue un polímata florentino del Renacimiento italiano. Fue a la vez pintor, anatomista, arquitecto, paleontólogo,3 artista, botánico, científico, escritor, escultor, filósofo, ingeniero, inventor, músico, poeta y urbanista. Murió acompañado de su fiel Francesco Melzi, a quien legó sus proyectos, diseños y pinturas.2 Tras pasar su infancia en su 
                </p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
                <h1>Prueba</h1>
                <p>
                Leonardo da Vinci (Leonardo di ser Piero da Vinci Loudspeaker.svg escuchar) (Vinci, 15 de abril de 14522 -Amboise, 2 de mayo de 1519) fue un polímata florentino del Renacimiento italiano. Fue a la vez pintor, anatomista, arquitecto, paleontólogo,3 artista, botánico, científico, escritor, escultor, filósofo, ingeniero, inventor, músico, poeta y urbanista. Murió acompañado de su fiel Francesco Melzi, a quien legó sus proyectos, diseños y pinturas.2 Tras pasar su infancia en su 
                </p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
                <h1>Prueba</h1>
                <p>
                Leonardo da Vinci (Leonardo di ser Piero da Vinci Loudspeaker.svg escuchar) (Vinci, 15 de abril de 14522 -Amboise, 2 de mayo de 1519) fue un polímata florentino del Renacimiento italiano. Fue a la vez pintor, anatomista, arquitecto, paleontólogo,3 artista, botánico, científico, escritor, escultor, filósofo, ingeniero, inventor, músico, poeta y urbanista. Murió acompañado de su fiel Francesco Melzi, a quien legó sus proyectos, diseños y pinturas.2 Tras pasar su infancia en su 
                </p>
        </div>
    </div>



</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Las grids de bootstrap tienen un ancho de 12 caben hasta 12 `col-md-1` en una pagina tu tienes un detalle en `<div class="col-md-6"><div class="col-md-3">` cambia  `col-md-3` por `col-md-6`.

> **Nota:** para aplicar las columnas de manera correcta es recomendado usar la clase `.row`.
>
> ```
> <div class="row">
>   <div class="col-sm-6>
>   </div>
> </div>
> ```
>
> Por cada columna anidada es recomendado tambien anidar la clase `.row` dentro de la columna
>
> ```
> <div class="row">
>   <div class="col-sm-6>
>     <div class="row">
>       <div class="col-sm-6">
>       </div>
>     </div>
>   </div>
> </div>
> ```

Ahora por cada `col-md-1` pueden caber otros 12 pero este perdería diseño, entonces para `col-md-*` mas grandes donde `*` puede ser `5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12` pueden caber otros 12 `col-md-1`.

```
<div class="row"> <!-- FILA 2-->
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <h1>Prueba</h1>
            <p>
            Leonardo da Vinci (Leonardo di ser Piero da Vinci Loudspeaker.svg escuchar) (Vinci, 15 de abril de 14522 -Amboise, 2 de mayo de 1519) fue un polímata florentino del Renacimiento italiano. Fue a la vez pintor, anatomista, arquitecto, paleontólogo,3 artista, botánico, científico, escritor, escultor, filósofo, ingeniero, inventor, músico, poeta y urbanista. Murió acompañado de su fiel Francesco Melzi, a quien legó sus proyectos, diseños y pinturas.2 Tras pasar su infancia en su 
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <h1>Prueba</h1>
            <p>
            Leonardo da Vinci (Leonardo di ser Piero da Vinci Loudspeaker.svg escuchar) (Vinci, 15 de abril de 14522 -Amboise, 2 de mayo de 1519) fue un polímata florentino del Renacimiento italiano. Fue a la vez pintor, anatomista, arquitecto, paleontólogo,3 artista, botánico, científico, escritor, escultor, filósofo, ingeniero, inventor, músico, poeta y urbanista. Murió acompañado de su fiel Francesco Melzi, a quien legó sus proyectos, diseños y pinturas.2 Tras pasar su infancia en su 
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <h1>Prueba</h1>
        <p>
        Leonardo da Vinci (Leonardo di ser Piero da Vinci Loudspeaker.svg escuchar) (Vinci, 15 de abril de 14522 -Amboise, 2 de mayo de 1519) fue un polímata florentino del Renacimiento italiano. Fue a la vez pintor, anatomista, arquitecto, paleontólogo,3 artista, botánico, científico, escritor, escultor, filósofo, ingeniero, inventor, músico, poeta y urbanista. Murió acompañado de su fiel Francesco Melzi, a quien legó sus proyectos, diseños y pinturas.2 Tras pasar su infancia en su 
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```